# Highcharts graph does not update with firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, highcharts, angularfire

```
$scope.hhData = $firebaseArray(aRef.orderByChild('ts').startAt('2018-07-02').limitToLast(50));
$scope.hhData.$loaded().then(function () {
            $scope.chartSeriesYArray = [];
            $scope.chartSeriesXArray = [];
            $scope.hhData.$watch(function() {

            angular.forEach($scope.hhData, function (value) {
                $scope.chartSeriesXArray.push(moment(value.ts).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss'));
                $scope.chartSeriesYArray.push(parseFloat(value.ein));
            });

            Highcharts.chart('chart', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Half Hourly Energy Consumption'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: $scope.chartSeriesXArray,
                    crosshair: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Energy (kwh)'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Meter01',
                    data: $scope.chartSeriesYArray
                }]
            });
        });
});
```

I wanted to be able to update the data live from Firebase into the chart. However, this code only allows the data to be updated once at the start and it never updates itself again. Is there any way to work around this? - tried the $interval method as suggested but it didn't work :(

Update: I managed to do so with $watch. However, this now means that my graph will only show when there is data coming in. If there is no data coming in (EG: when you just turn on the system) then no graph will show at all. This there another way around this

Comment: This is a demo of dynamic chart: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/ You can simply put the logic responsible for fetching the data in `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the $interval service to retrieve your data after a certain amount of time.

```
    $interval(function() {
$scope.hhData.$loaded().then(function () {
            $scope.chartSeriesYArray = [];
            $scope.chartSeriesXArray = [];

            angular.forEach($scope.hhData, function (value) {
                $scope.chartSeriesXArray.push(moment(value.ts).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss'));
                $scope.chartSeriesYArray.push(parseFloat(value.ein));
            });

            Highcharts.chart('chart', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Half Hourly Energy Consumption'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: $scope.chartSeriesXArray,
                    crosshair: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Energy (kwh)'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Meter01',
                    data: $scope.chartSeriesYArray
                }]
            });
        });
       }, 5000); //this function will run every 5 seconds
```

*don't forget you also need to add the $interval parameter to your controller, and the interval goes by milliseconds

```
app.controller('myCtrl',["$scope", "$interval", function($scope, $interval) {
    //code goes here
}]);
```

Comment: hi unfortunately this code does not seem to be working for me :( i did change my code to include a $watch to watch for data when it published